# Is there a reflecting telescope like as a Newtonian telescope but with a negative lens before the diagonal mirror?

Tags: telescope, newtonian-telescope, telescope-lens, mirror, cassegrain-telescope

A Cassegrain reflecting telescope contains a negative optical element between the main mirror and its focus. This increases it's focal length.
[image]

Is there a reflecting telescope like as a Newtonian telescope but with the negative lens before the diagonal mirror?
[image]

This question is not about a Barlow lens.

Comment: Optically it makes no difference whether you place such component in the place you indicate or outside the tube after the secondary mirror. It makes a difference for the usable aperture as it would require a larger secondary mirror or obstruction that the primary light does not pass the negative lens, thus it would reduce the light gathering capability of the telescope. Thus: likely not, as it only has disadvantages and not advantage (as far as I see)

Comment: @planetmaker "likely not, as it only has disadvantages and not advantage" I don't quite [follow your reasoning](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/54536/7982) can you elaborate?

Comment: I seem to remember a commercial telescope in the 1980s or 1990s that had this optical design. A cheap brand, too, like Tasco or something similar. The mirror was spherical instead of parabolic, and the lens was there to correct the spherical aberration.

Answer (score 4):

#### Yes! Those with a [Coudé focus](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43363/7982) and others

The following

- [this answer to *Why aren't reflector telescopes built with an offset secondary mirror?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49247/7982)
- [this answer to *Do telescopes exist that reflect the incoming light more than three times along their length?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43977/7982)
- [this answer to *How did I flip some mirrors around in the dark at 3 AM and change the focal length of a 24 inch Boller and Chivens?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43363/7982)
- [this answer to *Why is the Nancy Grace Roman Space Telescope's field of view shaped like a PacMan "ghost"?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/47067/7982)

show and link to a wide variety of reflecting telescope optical designs that include negative focal length mirrors and off-axis deflection. (Check them out, but two examples are shown below).

As for a proper, classical Newtonian with its truly 45° diagonal, **it will certainly have been tried by some amateur, somewhere, sometime, if for no other reason than they didn't have access to a primary mirror (blank, or figured) with a hole in the center.**

**Another reason would be viewing convenience** - that side-viewing option is pretty handy when your DIY portable telescope is big and heavy and for mechanical reasons a tall mount high enough to make bottom viewing with an external diagonal (inverting or fancy non-inverting) a pain.

Just for example, LOptics.com's [Building an open-tubed 12.5" F/12.5 Classical Cassegrain By Michael E. Lockwood](http://www.loptics.com/ATM/telescopes/12in_cass/cass_article/cass.html)

[image: LOptics.com's "Building an open-tubed 12.5" F/12.5 Classical Cassegrain" By Michael E. Lockwood http://www.loptics.com/ATM/telescopes/12in_cass/cass_article/cass.html]

[image: LOptics.com's "Building an open-tubed 12.5" F/12.5 Classical Cassegrain" By Michael E. Lockwood http://www.loptics.com/ATM/telescopes/12in_cass/cass_article/cass.html]

---

---

from https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49247/7982

> From [Design and development of a freeform active mirror for an astronomy application](http://dx.doi.org/10.1117/1.OE.53.3.031311) (also [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259645665_Design_and_development_of_a_freeform_active_mirror_for_an_astronomy_application)):
>
> [image: "Design and development of a freeform active mirror for an astronomy application" http://dx.doi.org/10.1117/1.OE.53.3.031311]

---

From https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43363/7982

[image]

---

from https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43977/7982

[image: optical diagram of ESOs Extremely Large Telescope] from the ESO ELT [optical diagram](https://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/eelt/telescope/design/) page, somewhat better diagram in  Figure 4 of [Hippler 2018](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.02693.pdf).

Comment: It looks like. But this is closer to the Cassegrain reflecting telescope with an additional diagonal mirror. The path length of the rays after the secondary mirror is approximately equal to the focal length of the primary mirror.

Comment: @Imyaf well "like a Newtonian" is not a very well-defined term. You haven't laid out your criteria in the question so answers have to judge for themselves what "like a Newtonian" does and does not mean. It would have been better if your comment "The path length of the rays after the secondary mirror is approximately equal to the focal length of the primary mirror" was in the original question if that's what you were thinking.